# Is there a way to calculate tgammaf(50) on a device using cuda?

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, wolfram-mathematica, random-seed

I am using stirling's approximation to calculate this, but I am having trouble storing the huge answer I get from Stirling's approximation. Is there any good way to store such a big number on the device?

Comment: Use `double` and `tgamma`?

Comment: Would someone like to add an answer to this question please?

Answer (score 3):

The CUDA [standard math library](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#mathematical-functions-appendix) supports both the double-precision function `tgamma` and the single-precision function`tgammaf`. Since Γ(50) is on the order of 10<sup>62</sup>, the result overflows the representable range of the `float` type and `tgammaf (50.0f)` thus returns infinity. However, the computation can proceed without overflow by using the double-precision function `tgamma` and storing the result to a `double` variable, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

__global__ void kernel (int a)
{
    float r = tgammaf ((float)a);
    double rr = tgamma ((double)a);
    printf ("tgammaf(%d) = %23.16e\ntgamma(%d)  = %23.16e\n", a, r, a, rr);
}

int main (void)
{
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(50);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The result of the above program should look like so:

```
tgammaf(50) =                     inf
tgamma(50)  =  6.0828186403426752e+62
```